# Character based folding in CodeMirror?

Tags: codemirror, adobe-brackets

How can i make the folding custom in CodeMirror;

I try to make an extension that allows me to add a folding to templates where it begins with `{%` and ends with `{% end` for Brackets editor.

But in Codemirror only allows some kind of folding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to write your own range-finding function. See the various ones that exist in `addon/fold`. `comment-fold.js` is probably the simplest.